# MySQL Connector/J SSL disable for X DevAPI

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm using mysql-connector-java 8.0.12 to connect MySQL DB via X DevAPI. I don't need to setup SSL for the localhost. How can I disable secure connection? My Java code is here followed by stack trace.

```
session = new SessionFactory().getSession("mysqlx://127.0.0.1:33060/world_x?user=root&password=");
System.out.println(session.isOpen());
```

ERROR: A secure connection is required but the server is not configured with SSL

```
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: A secure connection is required but the server is not configured with SSL.
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.x.XProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(XProtocol.java:159) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar:8.0.12]
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.x.XProtocol.beforeHandshake(XProtocol.java:226) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar:8.0.12]
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.x.XProtocol.connect(XProtocol.java:232) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar:8.0.12]
at com.mysql.cj.MysqlxSession.<init>(MysqlxSession.java:80) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar:8.0.12]
at com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:71) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar:8.0.12]
at com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.SessionFactory.getSession(SessionFactory.java:79) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar:8.0.12]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution from this [parameter references](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.11/source-code/com/mysql/cj/conf/PropertyDefinitions.java). Answering my question hopefully someone will save hours.  Changed URL as below

> mysqlx://127.0.0.1:33060/world_x?**xdevapi.ssl-mode=DISABLED**&user=root&password=